# Python Trig Functions Return Complex Numbers?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am writing code that accepts the degree by which a motor turns and uses that data to calculate the distance covered by the wheels (using distance = no. of rotations * distance covered per rotation).

It then makes an error adjustment (taking into consideration environmental factors such as friction).

Finally, using trigonometry, it calculates the distance moved along the x-axis and y-axis.

All the above is done by the function `straight` contained within the class `CoordinateManager`. This function is called by an instance of another class.

```
class CoordinateManager:
    goalcord = [20, 0]

    def __init__(self):
        self.curcord = [0, 0]
        self.theta = 0

    def get_compass_angle(self):
        compass = Sensor(address='in2')
        return compass.value(0)

    def turn(self, iangle, fangle):
        self.theta = self.theta + (fangle-iangle)

    def straight(self, turnangle):
        d = turnangle*2*3.14*2/360
        d = 1.8120132*(d**0.8938054)
        thetarad = radians(self.theta)
        dx = d*sin(thetarad)
        dy = d*cos(thetarad)
        self.curcord[0] += dx
        self.curcord[1] += dy
```

Printing both `d` and `self.theta` shows that they contain correct values.

This must mean that the array `self.curcord` has valid values too. However, this has not been the case. Printing the two elements of `self.curcord` outputs complex numbers (some big float + another big float**j**).

I can think of no logical explanation for this other than that the trigonometric functions must be returning complex numbers. However, I think the chances that a python built-in lib function returns wrong values are extraordinarily slim.

Is there any logical error that I may be overlooking?

Edit: I just tried changing the last two lines to:

```
self.curcord[0] += dx
self.curcord[1] += dy
```

I just tried using `.real` when displaying the values. Even though the values are real now, they are still wrong. I will look further into whether this is caused by some calculation error.

Comment: The `math` module only handles real numbers, but the `cmath` module works with complex numbers.

Comment: I am not handling complex numbers at all: all the inputs are real numbers.

Comment: FWIW, the standard numeric types _are_ actually complex numbers, but they usually have the imaginary part set to zero. Try this: `a=1;print(a.real, a.imag)`

Comment: But where did you get those trig functions? There's no `import` statement in the code you posted.

Comment: More specifically, `real` and `imag` come from the abstract base class `Complex` defined in the , not the type `complex`. `isinstance(1, complex)` is still `False`, but `isinstance(1, numbers.Complex)` is `True`.

Comment: I just tried using `.real` when displaying the values. Even though the values are real now, they are still wrong. I will look further into whether this is caused by some calculation error.

Comment: "I can think of no logical explanation for this other than that the trigonometric functions must be returning complex numbers." That's a good theory, but as I said earlier the `math` module doesn't handle complex numbers, although `cmath` does.  But you still haven't told us where you're importing your trig functions from.

Comment: Is `turnangle` always positive or can it be any real number?

Comment: @PM 2Ring I am importing the `math` module right at the start of the file using this: `from math import sin, cos, radians`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog `turnangle` can be any integer.

Comment: Ok. Then perhaps something else you're using imports & uses `cmath`. Can you make your code a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Sure! I'd more than happy to do that if you're willing to help.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks for the help, but the below answer helped solve the problem.

Comment: I forgot that you can give a negative value to the first operand of `**`. I should have tested... Sorry about that. :oops:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said in the comments above that `turnangle` can be any integer, the problem can be directly traced to this line:

```
d = 1.8120132*(d**0.8938054)
```

Since `turnangle` can be negative, the value of `d` before this line is executed can also be negative; a negative value raised to an arbitrary decimal power is in general *complex*.

Therefore the problem does not lie with the trig functions at all. The above also leads me to believe that when you said

> Printing both `d` and `self.theta` shows that they contain correct values

... you only did so after this line:

```
d = turnangle*2*3.14*2/360
```

This would explain why you wrongly thought the problem must lie elsewhere.

---

UPDATE:

1. It is a very bad habit to set a variable to some function of itself like you did. Try to use a different variable name to avoid confusion - as you saw above I had to refer to "this line" rather than by their variable names.
2. Perhaps something like this would work, assuming that the behaviour of the motor is the same regardless of the sign of `turnangle`?

   ```
   d = sign(d) * 1.8120132 * (abs(d) ** 0.8938054)
   ```